# .htaccess redirect from subfolder to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Google indexed my dev server :) I had test version of the site on him, now I want to 301 all the traffic to new server. But on dev I had this in folder and I don't know how to redirect.

Dev server: http://mydevserver.xyz/myfolder1/
Official page server: http://mypage_server.abc/

Tried:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/myfolder1/ http://mypage_server.abc/?
```

But redirects to http://mypage_server.abc not the subpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/myfolder1/(.*)$ http://mypage_server.abc/$1
```

Comment: Like a charm! Thanks!